# How do I deserialize into an existing object - C#

Tags: c#, serialization

In C#, after serializing an object to a file how would I deserialize the file back into an existing object without creating a new object?

All the examples I can find for custom serialization involve implementing a constructor that will be called upon deserialization which is exactly what I want except that I don't want the function to be a constructor.

Thanks!

Comment: What serializer are you using? or are you free to use any serializer?

Comment: I haven't started implementing any serialization so I'm free to use any but I was planning on using the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: "into an existing object" - seems overcomplicated and inefficient. Have you really thought this through?

Comment: It seems a lot less complicated to me. Instead of having to reinitialize my entire application I would just have to change a few member variables. Which is not only less complicated but also more efficient.

Comment: @Henk actually, I know of some efficiency-obsessive folks (not me, for a change) who explicitly requested that (hence why I added it in protobuf-net) - they wanted to use a micro-pool of objects that they could reset between uses, to absolutely minimise GC.

Comment: @rob deserializing over the top of an active application may be.... troublesome.

Comment: "Having to reinitialize my entire application" is not "having to construct an object". The fact that they're the same for you could prehaps be something that a single extra indirection will deal with.

Comment: @Jon So are you suggesting that I create a class that directly points to every class that needs to be serialized? This would work but it would be a pain to go and point every class that referenced one of these classes at the new deserialized instances.

Comment: Eh no, I was worried by your saying "reinitialise my entire application" that you had a class that directly pointed to every class that needed to be serialised. Why do you need to reinitialise your application when you deserialise something?

Comment: @Jon Well I have a class that indirectly points to everything that needs to be serialized. So I was planning on making it serializable which would cause its members to be serialized and it would eventually make it down to the classes that need to be serialized.

Comment: Well, that's normal, and then it's normal to deserialise into another instance of that class. Why do you need to avoid the constructor?

Comment: It just seems like a lot of extra work to recreate almost every class in my app when all I really need to do is load data into a few classes. For example lets say I have a calss A that has an instance of classes B and C. C is the only one that needs to be serialized so I make A and C serializable. Now when A is deserialized how would it get its old instance of B back? Or would I need to have some custom deserialization in A that creates a new instance of B and initializes it?

Answer (score 7):

Some serializers support callbacks; for example, both `BinaryFormatter` and `DataContractSerializer` (and protobuf-net, below) allow you to specify a before-serializaton callback, and since they *skip* the constructor, this may well be enough to initialize the object. The serializer is still *creating* it, though.

---

Most serializers are fussy about wanting to create the new object themselves, however some will allow you to deserialize into an existing object. Well, actually the only one that leaps to mind is protobuf-net (disclosure: I'm the author)...

This has 2 different features that might help here; for the *root* object (i.e. the outermost object in a graph) you can supply the existing object directly to either the `Merge` methods (in v1, also present in v2 for compatibility), or (in v2) the `Deserialize` methods; for example:

```
var obj = Serializer.Merge<YourType>(source, instance);
```

However, in a larger graph, you might want to supply other objects yourself (than just the root). The following is not exposed on the *attribute* API, but is a new feature in v2:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(SomeType)].SetFactory(factoryMethod);
```

where `factoryMethod` can be either the *name* of a `static` method in `SomeType` (that returns a `SomeType` instance), or can be a `MethodInfo` to any `static` method anywhere. The method can additionally (optionally) take the serialization-context as a parameter if you want. This method should then be used to supply all new instances of `SomeType`.

---

Note: protobuf-net is *not* quite the same as `BinaryFormatter`; for best effect, you need to tell it how to map your members - very similar to marking things as `[DataMember]` for WCF/DataContractSerializer. This *can* be attributes, but does not need to be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

1. So if I attach the OnDeserializingAttribute to a function then it will get called before deserialzation but it looks like it will only get the StreamingContext and not the SerializationInfo. Wouldn't I need the SerializationInfo to deserialize?

2. Your merge method would be ideal but I need to supply the object for more then just the root.

3. I think the SetFactory() method would work but it would be pretty messy as I would have to use a Singelton or some kind of public static state

Comment: Re "1"; you aren't intended to *deserialize* during the callback, hence why you only get the *context*. That callback gives you the opportunity to *prime* the type, similar to what you would have used in your custom creation code. You then either use the default deseriaize engine, or implement custom serialization *in addition to* the callback.

Comment: Re "2"; then `SetFactory` may be of use

Comment: Yes I think the SetFactory method would work. I accidentally hit enter before I finished my first comment. I still don't understand the callback method though. What do you mean by "prime the type"? At the time the callback is called the object that I want to deserialize into would have already been created so how would I switch out the empty object that the framework created?

Answer (score 5):

No problem, just use 2 classes. In getObject method you get your existing object

```
[Serializable]
public class McRealObjectHelper : IObjectReference, ISerializable 
{
    Object m_realObject;
    virtual object getObject(McObjectId id)
    {
        return id.GetObject();
    }
    public McRealObjectHelper(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        McObjectId id = (McObjectId)info.GetValue("ID", typeof(McObjectId));
        m_realObject = getObject(id);
        if(m_realObject == null)
            return;
        Type t = m_realObject.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] members = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(t, context);
        List<MemberInfo> deserializeMembers = new List<MemberInfo>(members.Length);
        List<object> data = new List<object>(members.Length);
        foreach(MemberInfo mi in members)
        {
            Type dataType = null;
            if(mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                dataType = fi.FieldType;
            } else if(mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property){
                PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                dataType = pi.PropertyType;
            }
            try
            {
                if(dataType != null){
                    data.Add(info.GetValue(mi.Name, dataType));
                    deserializeMembers.Add(mi);
                }
            }
            catch (SerializationException)
            {
                //some fiels are missing, new version, skip this fields
            }
        }
        FormatterServices.PopulateObjectMembers(m_realObject, deserializeMembers.ToArray(), data.ToArray());
    }

    public object GetRealObject( StreamingContext context )
    {
        return m_realObject;
    }
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
    }
}

public class McRealObjectBinder: SerializationBinder
{
    String assemVer;
    String typeVer;
    public McRealObjectBinder(String asmName, String typeName)
    {
        assemVer = asmName;
        typeVer = typeName;
    }
    public override Type BindToType( String assemblyName, String typeName ) 
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;
        if ( assemblyName.Equals( assemVer ) && typeName.Equals( typeVer ) )
        {
            return typeof(McRealObjectHelper);
        }
        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType( String.Format(  "{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName ) );
        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

Then, when deserialize:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter(null, context);
bf.Binder = new McRealObjectBinder(YourType.Assembly.FullName, YourType.FullName);
bf.Deserialize(memStream);
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a matter of copying a few fields, I would avoid all the trouble and take the simple route - deserialize into a new instance, then copy the appropriate fields to the existing instance. It will cost you a couple of extra copies, but you'll save a lot of time on debugging.

Comment: Yeah this would work but I was hoping there was a cleaner solution. Not sure if using the serialization framework would even be work it at this point. But I might end up doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unusual but it works:

```
[Serializable]
public class Pets
{
    public int Cats { get; set; }
    public int Dogs { get; set; }
}

public static class Utils
{
    public static byte[] BinarySerialize(object o)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
            f.Serialize(ms, o);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static dynamic BinaryDeserialize(byte[] bytes, dynamic o)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
            o = (dynamic)f.Deserialize(ms);
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

The deserialization is tricky with the dynamic which cannot be passed by reference.
And finally a no-sense test for proof:

```
Pets p = new Pets() { Cats = 0, Dogs = 3 };
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", p.Cats, p.Dogs);
byte[] serial = Utils.BinarySerialize(p);
p.Cats = 1;
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", p.Cats, p.Dogs);
p = Utils.BinaryDeserialize(serial, p);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", p.Cats, p.Dogs);
```

The output is the following:

```
0, 3
1, 3
0, 3
```

Replace memory strings with file stream and you will get the same results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Isn't this still creating a new instance of pets though? I tried testing it by writing a wrapper calss that has an instance of pets but when I call BinaryDeserialize() the wrapper class still points to an old instance pets and not the one with the deserialized values.

Comment: No it does not create a new instance of pets. Obviously the problem is within your wrapper or in the way you use it.

Comment: I added the following class: 
    public class PetOwner { public Pets ownedPets; } 
And I added the following code to the main method:
    PetOwner rob = new PetOwner();
    rob.ownedPets = p;
At the end of my main method if I call:
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", rob.ownedPets.Cats, rob.ownedPets.Dogs);
It prints 1,3 instead of 0,3. Can you see any problems with my wrapper?

Comment: Possibly (a hidden one). You have to serialize, update cats and deserialize using rob.ownedPets and not p

Comment: Ah I see. But what if I had several classes that pointed to p?

Comment: this is wrong. best case (bad design or a smart solution) is to use p for assigning default values to new instances.

Comment: What is wrong? Are you saying it is bad design to have a calss that is referenced by more then one calss?

Comment: Usually what is not documented as a practice is considered as bad design (not by me). Also threading issues will result a bad design case. - design, implementation or name it...

Comment: @drdigit, you are full of it lol. of course if you deserialize into the same variable, the variable will contain the saved values.The reference check shows you have not done anything new
`Pets p = new Pets {
 Cats = 0,
 Dogs = 3
};
Debug.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", p.Cats, p.Dogs);
byte[] serial = Utils.BinarySerialize(p);
p.Cats = 1;
Debug.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", p.Cats, p.Dogs);
Pets d = p;
//make a back up of p
p = Utils.BinaryDeserialize(serial, p);
Debug.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", p.Cats, p.Dogs);
Debug.WriteLine("d is p: {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(d, p));`

returns:

0, 3|1, 3|0, 3|d is p: False