# In place object deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization

Sorry if it is a trivial question.

If I want to serialize in xml my current object, I can, for instance, write a method like

```
public void xml_serialize_save(string fname)
{
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x =
         new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

     x.Serialize(new System.IO.StreamWriter(fname), this);            
}
```

Now, let's assume that I want to deserialize it in the same way, I would like to have a method such as

```
    public void xml_serialize_load(string fname)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

        this = (Data_param)x.Deserialize(new System.IO.StreamReader(fname));            
    }
```

which of course doesn't work because of the assignation to `this`.

**The question is:**

1. Am I obliged to deserialize on a temporary object, say

   ```
    Data_param temp = (Data_param)x.Deserialize(new System.IO.StreamReader(fname));
   ```

   ?
2. Should I then do the deep copy of the members from `temp` to *`this`* by hands?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8467198/573218

Comment: For #2 you don't need to do it by hand, you could use [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

Comment: To be explicit: no, XmlSerializer does not support that. Does it need to be XML? Or is your main objective simply to save/load the data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll go for a static reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually handle this is by creating a normal/public `Serialize` method, and an accompanying static/Shared `Deserialize` method.  Like so:

```
Public Class PersistantObject

  Public Sub Serialize(path as String)
    '  Do your serialization
  End Sub


  Public Shared Function Deserialize(path As String) As PersistantObject
    Dim result As PersistantObject = '  Assignment from deserializer

    Return result
  End Function

End Class
```

Use:

```
Dim obj As PersistantObject = PersistantObject.Deserialize(path)

obj.propertyA = newValue
obj.Serialize(path)
```

Note: I did not include de/serializer code because there are many different serializers (xml, json, binary, ...).